# Find the value smaller neighbors

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table:

[image]

What is the query that allows me to take the next smallest value based on what I entered?

Comment: 8 month members don't post pictures to a schema. Use text.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: If I have the value 83 would that height range it would restore the value 80

Comment: And if you have 70? Do you want 60 or 67?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your input instead of `myinput`:

```
select max(value)
from mytable
where value < myinput
```

EDIT:

We are filtering out all the elements, which have at least `myinput` value and find the maximum of the remaining elements, yielding the searched neighbour.

Comment: @adrianogand91, then you can accept my answer to help people having the same problem in the future.